# Efficient solution to update a variable based on values of several variables

Tags: java, design-patterns, callback

I have an update method which gets called every time the screen refreshes itself.

Inside this method I check the value of about about 50 objects to be zero. If all the values are zero I return a true else false is returned.

This is how I have implemented and want to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
public boolean update()
{
    float totalVel = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< this.numOfObjects; i++)
    {
         totalVel += BagOfWordsAverage[i];
    }

    if(totalVel == 0)
          return true;
    return false;
```

}

Depending on the boolean value returned, the caller of the udpate function allows certain inputs from the user. So if False is returned, the user cannot tap on the screen but in the case of true the user is allowed to do whatever she wants.

BagOfWordsAverage is a float array. I simply add the values of the entire array and check if the total is 0. No item in the array can take a negative value.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want to achieve? The challenge is that if the number of objects increased to 5000 will my method scale? Since this is for an App, speed is very important.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to return false as soon as you get a non-zero value right? Do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    if (foo[i] > 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but wouldn't checking an if condition 50 times and potentially 5000 times if the number of objects increase at every screen refresh drag the speed? I had implemented the if inside the loop but opted to the solution above to avoid the if conditions.

Comment: Essentially, no. Write a loop that compares 1 floating point number and time it. Then try it with a million.

Answer (score 2):

> If all the values are zero I return a true else false is returned.

So, as soon you see a non-zero value, you can return `false` immediately.
If you get out of the loop,
that must mean that everything was zero, and you can return `true`.

```
public boolean update()
{
    for(int i=0; i< this.numOfObjects; i++)
    {
         if (BagOfWordsAverage[i] > 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Btw a better way to iterate over arrays in Java:

```
public boolean update()
{
    for (float value : BagOfWordsAverage)
    {
         if (value > 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, the naming convention in Java is `camelCase` for variable names,
so I suggest to rename `BagOfWordsAverage` to `bagOfWordsAverage`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but wouldn't checking an if condition 50 times and potentially 5000 times if the number of objects increase at every screen refresh slow the app speed? I had implemented the if inside the loop but opted to the solution above to avoid the if conditions.

Comment: I would think summing should be slower than condition checks. But if the speed difference is a serious concern, then maybe you should benchmark it.

Comment: Yes that's a good point janos. I should benchmark the timing and then take a decision. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient solution is not to loop at all. You can have a map for every index with a value more than zero. If the map's size is 0, then you know that the array's total is zero.

You didn't post your code structure, but something like this might give you an idea:

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> moreThanZero = new HashMap<>();

public void someActionOnArray(int index) {
    /*
    do some action
     */

    float value = bagOfWordsAverage[index];

    if (value > 0) {
        moreThanZero.put(index, true);
    }

    if (value == 0) {
        if (moreThanZero.containsKey(index)) {
            moreThanZero.remove(index);
        }
    }
}

public boolean update() {
    return (moreThanZero.size() == 0);
}
```

Every method that modify the array should check the modified value at the current index. If it's more than zero, mark the index on the map. If it's less than zero, remove it if it exist.

This might cost you some memory if the size of indices with value more than zero is large, but you'll gain speed as you don't have to loop every time you refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but someActionOnArray will get called for all the array elements in every refresh effectively adding a loop somewhere. I cannot avoid the loop no matter what I do. But is it safe to say that doing additions on the values will be quicker than adding an if condition?

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could *slightly* improve the speed of your method would be to check each value and see if it is zero, and if it isn't, return false immediately. If you make it through the loop without finding any values other than zero, you can return true.

```
public boolean update()
{
    for(int i=0; i< this.numOfObjects; i++)
    {
         if (BagOfWordsAverage[i] != 0)
         {
             return false;
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that while the actual average case run-time of your function will improve with this change (i.e if there is a nonzero in the middle of the array, your run-time will be O(n/2) rather than O(n)), big-O analysis typically omits all but the highest-order function, and considers things like O(3n), O(n/2) to be simplified to simply O(n), as they are run on linear time.

As far as your question regarding an array of 5000 items, average case would take half the time of your original function, but in the worst case, the speed would be the same. If there are no assumptions we can make about where the possible location of these nonzero numbers would be, there is no other option than to check each index of the array individually.

Hopefully this helps.